# Getting error while connecting Github through ssh key using ROR

Tags: 14.04, ssh, git, ruby-on-rails

I have an issue. I was `Configuring Git` using the following command for my ROR application. I added the ssh key and tried to check this using `ssh -T git@github.com` command it is throwing the following error.

Error:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I generated the ssh key using following command.

```
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config --global user.email "YOUR@EMAIL.com"
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "YOUR@EMAIL.com"
```

After that i added the key using this link(https://github.com/settings/ssh).But when i tried to test it using below command it is throwing this error.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: GitHub has a FAQ for this at https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/. See if that helps.

Comment: @edwinksl : Did not get any help frpm this page.

Answer (score 0):

It asks for filename when you create the key, please don't give any file name
then only you will not fail.
Since the git clone tries to find the ida_rsa file which git can't find if you give some name at the time of creation of key. That worked for me.